# vim find only files but not directories

Tags: vim

I know ctrlp can do this, but how to use vim's native `:find` command to acheive this?
I use `:find` command more often than ctrlp as it takes less keystrokes.
Also, sometimes I need to use this function in my script, for example:

```
let filename = GetFileName()  
execute 'find '.filename
```

I seldom have the need to find a directory.
I have set path=** to enable recursive search.
Suppose /home/tiny/project is the current directory, and I try to find a file named 'tmp', typing :fin tmp may also open a directory browser if a directory like /home/tiny/project/xxx/tmp/ exists, and this is not I want.

Comment: Do you want to restrict `:find` to only find files? This is already how it works.

Comment: Or Are you trying to find a file without caring to type the full path? if so, then does `:set path+=**` followed by `:find file` helps

Comment: @romainl yes, I want only files bt not directories, but vim will find directories too.  I have set path+=** to enable recursive search.    For example, /home/tiny is the current directory, I try to find a file named tmp, but typing :find   tmp may open a directory browser if /home/tiny/tmp/ exists.